Expo App stuck on Splash Screen in Expo SDK 50
My app was working fine only a till only a few days back for some reason the app was getting stuck on the splash screen. This is on both Android and iOS simulators.
I tried updating all my dependancies to the latest versions. I tried reinstalling all packages but that didn't work either. I'm quite confused at this point.

I'm currently running the app in Expo Go.

{
  "name": "myapp",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "prebuild": "expo prebuild",
    "doctor": "expo-doctor@latest",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.6.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~50.0.15",
    "expo-av": "^13.10.5",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}



I noticed this started happening after upgrading to Expo 50 too

If you are preventing Splashscreen from auto-hiding, this might be helpful. If you use the Callback function, make sure that the "onLayout" property is only on the View element. On the older version of the SDK, you could use the "onLayout" property on some other elements, but on the newer version, it no longer works. I spent a few days debugging until I found that the "onLayout" property on the Stack element for some reason doesn't work on the newer version of the SDK, but it did before. I think it's my fault that I didn't follow the documentation well in the previous version of the application, so I had problems later. I hope this can help you.

I TRIED EVERYTHING, BUT FINALLY FIXED IT BY USING THE BELOW DEPENDENCIES
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
"axios": "^1.7.2",
"expo": "~51.0.26",
"expo-camera": "~15.0.14",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-image": "~1.12.13",
"expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
"expo-location": "~17.0.1",
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.15",
"expo-router": "~3.5.21",
"expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
"firebase": "^10.12.2",
"jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-picker-select": "^9.1.3",

// THE BELOW ONES FIXED THE STUCK SPLASH SCREEN, I DON'T KNOW EXACTLY WHAT AND WHY BUT ADD THE BELOW AND GET ON WITH YOUR LIFE, WELCOME
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1"

